# Merge the [dog-door] and [pet-door] tags

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

The [dog-door](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dog-door) tag was created earlier today as part of an approved [suggested edit](https://diy.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/8620).  We already have a [pet-door](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pet-door) tag that is applicable to that question.  The [suggested tag wiki](https://diy.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/8622) for [dog-door](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dog-door) even indicates that its creator thinks it's more general than just doors for dogs:

> pertains to doors exclusive to pets, especially dogs and cats

Can we create a synonym between the [dog-door](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dog-door) tag and the [pet-door](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pet-door) tag, or merge them outright?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Done. I've made them synonyms for now, but there was only one [dog-door](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dog-door) question so I just changed it over manually.

Comment: Thank you!  I submitted edits to add dog-door to 2 other questions, but the edits haven't been approved yet.  Maybe you could reject them?

Comment: Yup, I've been working through them. Not sure I got them all.

Answer (score 1):

I agree:  a synonym would be better.  Also, one should be created for cat-door.  I submitted an excerpt and description for dog-door, but they don't seem to be visible yet.  I suggest merging that content to pet-door.

I looked for a way to create a synonym, but apparently my low reputation doesn't even present the option to suggest a synonym.  (I have had the ability on StackOverflow for so long, I forget it was an earned privilege.)